# Difference between "reg save" and "reg export"?

Tags: windows

Using the Windows **cmd** command `reg`:

```
reg save
```

Saves a copy of specified subkeys, entries, and values of the registry in a specified file.

```
reg export
```

Creates a copy of specified subkeys, entries, and values into a file so that it can be transferred to other servers.

What's the difference between them, except the file being generated as `.hiv` or `.reg`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generated file *is* the difference.

`save` saves the branch into the Registry's native "hive" format. This preserves key ownership and ACLs, so is best suited for backups and restoring on the same machine.

`export` exports it into a textual format, suitable for distribution since the .reg format does not preserve any metadata.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just that the generated files are different. I noticed that what happens when you use the .reg file vs when you use the .hiv file is quite different

When you import a .reg file, you don't have to specify a path. It writes to your registry based on the .reg file, and leaves new registry keys and entries created between export and import untouched.

Whereas when you import a .hiv file, you have to specify a path. New registry keys and entries created between export and import are deleted.

---

Here's an example to illustrate.

1. Create a dummy key with a dummy entry

   ```
   reg add hkcu\test
   reg add hkcu\test /v entry /t REG_DWORD /d 1
   ```
2. If you run `reg query hkcu\test` you will see this

   > `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\test`
   >       `(Default)    REG_SZ`
   >       `entry    REG_DWORD    0x1`
3. Export to a .reg file and to a .hiv file

   ```
   reg export hkcu\test test.reg
   reg save hkcu\test test.hiv
   ```
4. Then create a new entry and a new subkey

   ```
   reg add hkcu\test /v new_entry /t REG_SZ /d "ayy lmao"
   reg add hkcu\test\new_key
   ```
5. If you run `reg query hkcu\test` you will see this

   > `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\test`
   >       `(Default)    REG_SZ`
   >       `entry    REG_DWORD    0x1`
   >       `new_entry    REG_SZ    ayy lmao`
   >
   > `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\test\new_key`
6. Import the .reg file we created earlier

   ```
   reg import test.reg
   ```

   If you run `reg query hkcu\test`, you will see the same output from #5.
7. Import the .hiv file we create earlier

   ```
   reg restore hkcu\test test.hiv
   ```

   If you run `reg query hkcu\test`, you will find that the new items we created in #4 is gone and we get the same output as #2.

Comment: Good description of a crucial difference.  Could be disastrous if used wrong.